# Test case Code coverage using Coverage.py and Pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, code-coverage, coverage.py

I'm trying to get the executed code out of each Pytest Test case -in order to make a debuger-, now it's possible in Coverage module apis  i will use the following code:

```
cov.start()
assert nrm.mySqrt(x) == 3 // this is a test case using Pytest
cov.stop()
cov.json_report()
cov.erase()// after this line i repeat the steps top
```

but it's not practical, so if I used the `coverage run - m pytest fileName` command it will not give me a report for each case, I'm trying to use the plugin in order to apply some special case where if the executed line is including assert I want to get a JSON report and the erase the data, will I be able to do that? or should I try to find a way to implant the code above for each test case?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to do and if there is an easier way to do this, but to do it the way you described you can just use an `autouse` fixture (e.g. start coverage before yielding, stop it afterwards). Maybe using the `pytest-cov` plugin would help you otherwise.

Comment: I'd also like to hear more about what you are trying to do. "In order to make a debugger"?  Coverage.py has a feature called "contexts" that can be used to collect coverage data individually for each test: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/contexts.html. Perhaps that will give you the information you need?